# Sum with two conditions in Excel Table

Tags: excel-2007

I'm new to this forum, so if I make mistakes, tell me so I can learn ;).

So the question is, I want to make a summation of a column of a table in Excel, but only if it complies with two conditions. `Table1` has 3 columns: `Col1` contains a Date, `Col2` a price and `Col3` a catagory in which the price is logged.

I want the sum of all prices, for which the date falls within a certain month, and the Category complies with a choosen Category.
The code for both individual requirements works, and looks like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(MONTH(Table1[Date])=MONTH(A3);Table1[Price];0))}
{=SUM(IF(Table1[Category]="Category1";Table1[Price];0))}
```

However, the combined sum, `=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH(Table1[Date])=MONTH(A3);Table1[Category]="Category1");Table1[Price];0))` does not work.

Do you know what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not really "do wrong" though perhaps a poor choice of approach (in my opinion, I happen not to be a fan of structured references). It is just that `AND` here does not return an array, only either TRUE (when the result would be the sum of *all* prices) or, much more likely FALSE (any one condition does not match, when the result is `0`).

Instead I would recommend a [PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-PivotTables-74ce8afc-2446-4816-80ee-20ca7fb71793).

Comment: That is exactly what I finally did. I was not familiair with Pivots yet.
Thanks for your reply!!